# AppBase / Reactive search : strategy to filter from an array of ids

Tags: reactivesearch

I'm using the reactive search on a react web app and I'm trying to find a way to be able to switch from "all items" to "favorite items" for which I have an array of ids.

I've tried three different strategies, but none appears satisfying:

1. I've set up a DataController with a custom query on "terms", but it only works one way : I can filter the items, but then I can't unfilter them and get back to the unfiltered.
2. I also tried to use the multilist dropdown with the defaultSelected prop but then if I clear the filter I can't find a way to programmatically set the values.
3. Eventually I can provide my own filter inside the onData function and choose to show / not show the item whether it appears on the list of ids - but this feels hacky and I'd prefer - if possible - to integrate the functionality directly to the reactiveBase.

What would be the best strategy to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the best solution :

1- I need to **set a new query** each time there is a change in the component's value.

2- The only way to get a "setQuery" function as prop is by using a **ReactiveComponent** and **not a DataController** (I wonder what is the use of DataController then !).

3- ReactiveComponent is correctly demonstrated [here](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/reactivecomponent.html).

Comment: DataController is a legacy component and may be removed in the future. `ReactiveComponent` certainly gives you more control.